# Prevent android activities from reloading

Tags: java, android

I made an Android app with 5 tabs using this example: http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html but when I swype to the first tab, then swype to the 5th tab and than swype back to the first tab, the first, second and third tabs reload. Is there a way to prevent these tabs from reloading?

Comment: You mean the Fragments? set your retainfragments in memory to 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setOffscreenPageLimit(5);//on your viewpager
```